# Display current time in epoch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, epoch

I'm trying to display the current time in epoch, i'm not sure if this is correct, but i'm sure it's not since it's giving me an error:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *epochDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:currentDate];
```

Any idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Sending NSDate strong to parameter of incompatible type NSTimerInterval

Comment: What do you mean by *"current time in epoch"*? What result do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by "epoch date"?  If you mean milliseconds since 1970 then use `long epochDate = (long) (1000.0 * [NSDate timeIntervalSince1970:currentDate]);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimeInterval epoch = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%f", epoch);
```

Or better yet, this gives just the integer part of the time:

```
int epoch = round([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSLog(@"%d", epoch);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *epochTime = @"1347522689";
NSTimeInterval epochInterval = [epochTime longLongValue];
NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epochInterval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterEpoch = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterEpoch setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSString *epochDate = [dateFormatterEpoch stringFromDate:epochNSDate];

NSDate *currentDateNSDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterCurrent = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterCurrent setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatterCurrent stringFromDate:currentDateNSDate];


NSLog(@"epochDate = %@",epochDate);
NSLog(@"currentDate = %@", currentDate);

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:epochNSDate toDate:currentDateNSDate options:0];

NSInteger year = [components month];
NSInteger months = [components month];
NSInteger days = [components day];
NSInteger hours = [components hour];
NSInteger min = [components minute];
NSInteger sec = [components second];


NSLog(@"Year Difference = %@\n Month Difference = %@\n, Days Difference = %@\n, Hours Difference = %@\n ,Minutes Difference = %@\n second Difference = %@\n", [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:year] stringValue] ,[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:months] stringValue], [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:days] stringValue], [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:hours] stringValue], [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:min] stringValue],[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sec] stringValue]);
```

Comment: He just wants your first line.

Answer (score 0):

For converting your date to epoch. you need to use `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` method like this below

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"epochDate: %f",([date timeIntervalSince1970]);
```