# Get current time converted into Epoch time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, epoch

I need a way to get the current date converted into epoch time e.g: 12343215325

I've tried so many things, but since im new i might be doing stupid stuff.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a NSDate to milliseconds epoch time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321055/convert-a-nsdate-to-milliseconds-epoch-time)

Comment: Where is the difference to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885867/display-current-time-in-epoch ? It would be better to *clarify* your question (in particular because several people tried to answer it) instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 18):

This can be done with the NSDate class:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval nowEpochSeconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Note that `timeIntervalSince1970` is an instance method that returns an `NSTimeInterval`. However, if we look at the definition of `NSTimeInterval`:

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

So we simply have a `double` holding current seconds since 00:00:00 on 1 Jan 1970, so output format is the same as with a `double` format. This value is precise to sub-milliseconds so we can get milliseconds-epoch-time by multiplying by 1000.

Comment: Does timeIntervalSince1970 give value in GMT or based on user timezone?

Answer (score 0):

in c
declare a tm structure
struct tm yourtm;
fill in the tm structure with the current local date and time.
then call mktime ( &yourtm ) and it will return the number of seconds since
Jan 1, 1970 in GMT.

Comment: in unix korn shell -> typeset -i sec_since_epoch=`date +%s`